# Can someone with intimate knowledge of the language break down this phrase "何食べたら大きくれるの"

Tags: particles

I know the meaning of this, but I want to understand the structure of it like the grammar/or conjugation used to get that meaning.

Comment: [Context, please.](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2189/what-should-i-do-if-i-was-asked-for-the-context-why-is-it-important?cb=1)

Comment: A kid asking his dad

Comment: `何食べたら大きくれるの` <-- should be a typo for 何食べたら大きく**な**れるの.

Comment: @Chocolate Interesting, that makes more sense now. I found this phrase in a netflix show. Is it possible that the な is omitted in normal everyday speech ?

Comment: What is the show? When does the line appear? This is the kind of context that was being requested.

Comment: なれる never contracts to れる. A typo is a typo, not an omission. So are you fine with the sentence if it is なれる? Can we resolve this as a typo-question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might have incomplete knowledge of slang or dialects or something, but I'm very confident this is a typo. As mentioned in comments, it looks like it should be “何食べたら大きく**な**れるの”, meaning roughly "what should I eat to get big(ger)?"

I've been living in Japan for a while, and I've never heard a construction like the one you posted, without な. れる by itself is not a word that I know of.